# multiinput from submission in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to submit a form in react js I have multiple files

```
this.state = {
  allValues: [],
};
```

```
changeHandler = (e) => {
  this.setState({ ...this.allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

onsubmbit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.allValues);
};
<form onSubmit={this.onsubmbit}>
  <input type='text' name='bloodsugar' onChange={this.changeHandler} value='' />

  <input
    type='text'
    name='bloodpressure'
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    value=''
  />

  <button type='submit' style={styles.subbtn}>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>;
```

I am trying to submit a form in react js I have multiple files
I am trying to submit this form

`console.log(this.state.allValues);` when i console log it in submit function i want data as

```
{
    bloodsugar:data of bloodsugar,
    bloodpressure:data of bloodsugar,
}
```

when I console log it in submit function I want data like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `value` of each input field from the `state` that you set with `changeHandler` method. Additionally, you need to update the `changeHandler` method to update the `state.allValues` as follows.

(Following is the example code I used to test locally. Do the necessary modifications to fit it to your implementation)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allValues: {
        bloodsugar: "",
        bloodpressure: "",
      },
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      allValues: { ...this.state.allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
    });
  };

  onsubmbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.allValues);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onsubmbit}>
        <div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: "4rem", padding: "15px" }}>
            <i className="fa fa-level-up"></i>
          </div>
          <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            <strong>Enter your blood sugar level</strong>
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="bloodsugar"
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
              value={this.state.allValues.bloodsugar}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: "4rem", padding: "15px" }}>
            <i className="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
          </div>
          <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            <strong>Enter your blood pressure level</strong>
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="bloodpressure"
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
              value={this.state.allValues.bloodpressure}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```